# "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

Tags: ssis

this might be a really old question, but I am getting this error using a SSIS package that someone created, I checked the error and it seems that a column from the flat file that the package is reading has a lot of blank spaces or maybe tabs that make the field longer that it should be.

1.-  I tried to change the outputcolumnwidth from 50 to 100 or + but it is not working.
2.-  I search on this page but all make reference to csv files or add an step creating an xls files,  but I need to see if is possible to solve it without doing it because another option that I though was to remove the file from reading it.

any advice is appreciated...

Comment: At the end I decided to edit the txt file because I really need to process this file asap, but I will appreciate an answer on how to solve this issue to avoid it on the future.

Comment: anyone with a good idea on how to solve this without creating additional files